Evaluate $\int_{-\frac{1}{3}}^{1}\left(\sqrt[3]{1+\sqrt{1-x^{3}}}+\sqrt[3]{1-\sqrt{1-x^{3}}}\right)dx$
Evaluate $$\int_{-\frac{1}{3}}^{1}\left(\sqrt[3]{1+\sqrt{1-x^{3}}}+\sqrt[3]{1-\sqrt{1-x^{3}}}\right)dx$$
The Question is from MIT BEE $2024$ which I found in the internet after searching for $2$ days. Now I am thinking this integral for nearly $5$ days.
What I thought for these $5$ days is to break the integral into a cube form. That is we know that $\sqrt[3]{x^{3}}=x$. I am thinking to evaluate this following integral in this way.
I broke $(1+\sqrt{1-x^{3}})$ as $\frac{1}{2}(2+2\sqrt{1-x^{3}})$
Now I thought of applying the formula of $(a+b)^{2}$.
That is we can assume that $$(1+\sqrt{1-x^{3}})=\frac{1}{2}(2+2\sqrt{1-x^{3}})$$
Now I wrote $(1-x^{3})$ as $(1-x^{\frac{3}{2}})(1+x^{\frac{3}{2}})$.
That is $$\frac{1}{2}(2+2\sqrt{1-x^{3}})=\frac{1}{2}[(1+x^{\frac{3}{2}})+(1-x^{\frac{3}{2}})+2\sqrt{(1-x^{\frac{3}{2}})(1+x^{\frac{3}{2}})}]$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\left[\left(\sqrt{1+x^{\frac{3}{2}}}\right)^{2}+\left(\sqrt{1-x^{\frac{3}{2}}}\right)^{2}+2\sqrt{(1-x^{\frac{3}{2}})(1+x^{\frac{3}{2}})}\right]$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\left(\sqrt{1-x^{\frac{3}{2}}}+\sqrt{1+x^{\frac{3}{2}}}\right)^{2}$$
Similarly I will again try to break $(1-\sqrt{1-x^{3}})$ as $\frac{1}{2}(2-2\sqrt{1-x^{3}})$
That is I can again say that $$\frac{1}{2}(2-2\sqrt{1-x^{3}})=\frac{1}{2}[(1+x^{\frac{3}{2}})+(1-x^{\frac{3}{2}})-2\sqrt{(1-x^{\frac{3}{2}})(1+x^{\frac{3}{2}})}]$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\left[\left(\sqrt{1+x^{\frac{3}{2}}}\right)^{2}+\left(\sqrt{1-x^{\frac{3}{2}}}\right)^{2}-2\sqrt{(1-x^{\frac{3}{2}})(1+x^{\frac{3}{2}})}\right]$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\left(\sqrt{1-x^{\frac{3}{2}}}-\sqrt{1+x^{\frac{3}{2}}}\right)^{2}$$
But I am not getting any benefit from after this step. Because still now the integral is looking messy.
Any benefit will be highly Appreciated.
I am available at anytime on anyday.

Recently I am seeing my questions are getting downvoated without any reason ? What is this ? Shall I stop asking then ? What is the actual guideline followed in this community then ? If my question gets downvoated even after showing the approach then that cannot be the guideline of this community. Please look into this matter

Interesting integral! A small hint is to look at Cardano's method for solving a cubic equation. I can provide a detailed answer, if you can wait a few hours :-)

Yes. Thank you for your comment. You are really inspiring me. But uncertainly my question got downvoated without any reason. Thank you very  much @Bml. Go Ahead.

Also the roots of the cubic $(1-x^{3})$ are $1$ and $\omega^{2}+\omega+1=0$. So here I don't think cardano's method will be helpful in any way

Are you sure you are comfortable having your email address public? You could end up with a lot of spam!

Yes @Shaun. For learning purpose, it's fine

Regarding your first comment, please note that people downvote and vote to close questions for all kinds of reasons. Maybe it's because a question is badly worded, the solution is obvious, they're salty, or IDK. As long as you show you're willing to learn then you'll be fine.

The real solution to the equation $z^3+pz+q=0$ can be expressed as $\sqrt[3]{(\frac{-q}{2})+\sqrt{(\frac{-q}{2})^2+(\frac{p}{3})^3}}+\sqrt[3]{(\frac{-q}{2})-\sqrt{(\frac{-q}{2})^2+(\frac{p}{3})^3}}$
Let the integral in question be $\int^1_{-\frac{1}{3}}u dx$
Then $u$ can be thought of as the solution to the equation $u^3+pu+q=0$ (I)
This makes it easy to see that $\frac{-q}{2}=1\to q=-2 \land \frac{p}{3}=-x\to p=-3x $
So from  (I)  we get
$$u^3-3xu-2=0\to x=\frac{u^2}{3}-\frac{2}{3u}\to dx=(\frac{2u}{3}+\frac{2}{3u^2})du$$
The limits become :
$$x_1=-\frac{1}{3}\to u^3+u-2=0\implies u=1\\x_2=1\to u^3-3u-2=0\implies u=2$$
Hence:
$$I=\int^2_1 u(\frac{2u}{3}+\frac{2}{3u^2})du= \frac{14}{9}+\frac{2}{3}\log(2) $$

Great job. It's a really great job. @Antony Theo. I could have never solved it even thinking it for $50$ years also.

$$I=\int_{-\frac{1}{3}}^{1}\left(\sqrt[3]{1+\sqrt{1-x^{3}}}+\sqrt[3]{1-\sqrt{1-x^{3}}}\right)dx$$

Since the substitution of $t=\left(\sqrt[3]{1+\sqrt{1-x^{3}}}+\sqrt[3]{1-\sqrt{1-x^{3}}}\right)$ isn’t obviously preferred,
Building up to an equation which simplifies our integrand to a great deal,
Consider,
$$t=a+b$$
Cubing both sides,
$$t^3=a^3+b^3+3abt$$
Now substitute the below,
$$a=\sqrt[3]{1+\sqrt{1-x^{3}}}, b=\sqrt[3]{1-\sqrt{1-x^{3}}}$$
$$t^3=2+3\left(\sqrt[3]{1+\sqrt{1-x^{3}}}\right)\left(\sqrt[3]{1-\sqrt{1-x^{3}}}\right)t$$
$$t^3=2+3\left(\sqrt[3]{(1+\sqrt{1-x^{3}})(1-\sqrt{1-x^{3}}})\right)t$$
Using $a^2-b^2=(a+b)(a-b)$ and little more simplification and you get,
$$x=\frac{t^3-2}{3t}\implies dx=\frac{2}{3}\left(t+\frac{1}{t^2}\right)\,dt, \left[\frac{-1}{3},1\right]\to [1,2]$$
So your integral now becomes,
$$I=\frac{2}{3}\int_1^2\left(t^2+\frac{1}{t}\right)\,dt=\frac{14}{9}+\frac{2}{3}\ln(2)$$
I hope the above integral is straightforward
Theo's answer involves the Cardano formula, very interesting stuff

$$I=\int_{-\frac{1}{3}}^{1}\left(\sqrt[3]{1+\sqrt{1-x^{3}}}+\sqrt[3]{1-\sqrt{1-x^{3}}}\right)dx$$
By direct substitution:
Let $$u=\left(\sqrt[3]{1+\sqrt{1-x^{3}}}+\sqrt[3]{1-\sqrt{1-x^{3}}}\right).\tag1$$ Then, $u^3=2+3ux$. Thus, $x=\frac{u^2}3-\frac2{3u}$ and $dx=(\frac{2u}3+\frac2{3u^2})du.$
Change of integral bounds by equation $(1)$:

$$x=1\implies u=1+1=2.$$
$$x=-\frac13\implies u=\frac{\sqrt[3]{3\sqrt3+2\sqrt7}-\sqrt[3]{2\sqrt7-3\sqrt3}}{\sqrt3}=\frac{\sqrt{5+\sqrt{21}}-\sqrt{5-\sqrt{21}}}{\sqrt6}=\frac{(\sqrt{\frac72}+\sqrt{\frac32})-(\sqrt{\frac72}-\sqrt{\frac32})}{\sqrt6}=1!$$
Hence, $I=\int_1^2u(\frac{2u}3+\frac2{3u^2})du=\frac23(\frac73+\ln2)$.

